# mysql don't count row twice if column data is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I am counting the rows in a mysql table called `ptb_profile_views`.

My table looks like this:

```
id  |  profile_id   | viewed_profile_id  |  date_time  |

1          1                  6              
2          2                  6
3          2                  6
4          2                  6
5          3                  6
```

At the moment my query counts all the rows in the table. However, I only want it to count the rows which do not contain duplicate values in `profile_id`.

So if user 2/profile_id 2 views user 6's profile several times, which in this case they do, I only want the query to count it once. I am trying to use distinct but its not working. Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong?

```
function check_profile_views() {
    global $connection;
    global $_SESSION;
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) FROM ptb_profile_views WHERE viewed_profile_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND profile_id='0'";
    $check_profile_views_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($check_profile_views_set);
    return $check_profile_views_set;        
}
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870709/mysql-do-not-count-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (assuming viewed_profile_id is 6):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id) FROM ptb_profile_views WHERE viewed_profile_id=6
```