# mysql do not count duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

i have a a table called ptb_profile_views;

```
id  |  profile_id  |  viewed_profile  |  date

1          1               5
2          1               5
3          1               5
4          2               5
5          3               5
```

ok so in this example users 1,2 ans 3 are checking out user 5's profile,

the mysql i've got here is suppose to count the number of views a user has got, but where user 1 has checked out user 5 several times i do not want to return duplicate rows,

so instead of saying user 5 has been viewed 5 times, they will have only actually been viewed 3 times because i only want to count distinct values.

heres my mysql can someone please help me:

```
function check_profile_views() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(profile_id) FROM ptb_profile_views WHERE viewed_profile_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND profile_id!='0'";
            $check_profile_views_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_profile_views_set);
            return $check_profile_views_set;        
        }
```

the php:

```
$check_profile_views_set = check_profile_views();
while ($views = mysql_fetch_array($check_profile_views_set)) {  
?>
<? echo"". $views['COUNT(profile_id)'] ."";?> viewed your profile
```

Answer (score 10):

just add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id) totalCOUNT FROM ptb_profile_views...
```

and echo the alias,

```
$views['totalCOUNT']
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1665b/2)